# Call the client begins with a mp3 voice message

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am very new to Twilio and Python.
I am trying to make a phone call by Twilio and the phone call begins with a pre-recorded MP3/YouTube voice message. I know I can customize the TwiML and use  action. However, do I have to upgrade my account from free trial account to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a Twilio account you should have an `account_sid` and an `auth_token`. Here is an example from [The Twilio Python Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-python). Change the values to suit your environment.

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                    url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                    to='+14155551212',
                    from_='+15017122661'
                )

print(call.sid)
```

In this case the `http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml` *TwiML* file is used as an example. From your Twilio account you should be able to create your own *TwiML* files and customize the interaction as needed.

Comment: Can I do it with a free trial account? The call from Twilio said I need a paid account to remove the automatic voice message.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. In order to make calls without the message about upgrading your account, you do need to upgrade your account. The free trial account is so that you can test, when you want to move your application to production and call other people you need to upgrade your account.